# Isotope filtering based on date field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-isotope

I've an isotope structure like this;

```
<div class="grid">
   <div class="element-item transition metal" data-category="category-item">
       <h2 class="name">Gold</h2>
       <input type="hidden" value="01/02/2015" class="crdate">
   </div>
   <div class="element-item metalloid" data-category="category-item">
       <h2 class="name">Antimony</h2>
       <input type="hidden" value="04/02/2015" class="crdate">
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to sort the data with the hidden date field value.

I've two radio buttons;

```
<input type="radio" name="sortdate" class="sort_new" value="new">New<br>
<input type="radio" name="sortdate" class="sort_old" value="old">Old
```

My requirement is when I click on the radio buttons, I want to sort the data based on the date field value. Suppose if I click on "New" radio button, then the item with new date will be displayed top and vice versa.

My javascript structure like this;

```
$('.sort_new').on('click', function () {
          $('.grid').isotope({
                getSortData: {
                    date: function ( itemElem  ) {
                        return $( itemElem ).find('.crdate').val();
                    }
                },
                sortBy: 'date',
                sortAscending: false,
            });

      });

    $('.sort_old').on('click', function () {
          $('.grid').isotope({
                getSortData: {
                    date: function ( itemElem  ) {
                        return $( itemElem ).find('.crdate').val();
                    }
                },
                sortBy: 'date',
                sortAscending: true,
            });

      });
```

Please help me to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: What seems to be the problem in your page? do you have problem with isotope sorting or attaching the correct click/change events?

Comment: Elements are not sorting when I click on the radio buttons. Eg: When I click on "New" radio button, the item with latest date will be displayed at top and all others with their dates. And similar case for "Old" radio button click; I mean old date first then next... etc
Now its not working properly. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing the formatted date in input value with the actual timestamp and modify your JS:

```
$('.sort_new').on('click', function () {
    $('.grid').isotope({
        getSortData: {
            date: function ( itemElem  ) {
                return parseInt($( itemElem ).find('.crdate').val(), 10);
            }
        },
        sortBy: 'date',
        sortAscending: false,
    });
});

$('.sort_old').on('click', function () {
    $('.grid').isotope({
        getSortData: {
            date: function ( itemElem  ) {
                return parseInt($( itemElem ).find('.crdate').val(), 10);
            }
        },
        sortBy: 'date',
        sortAscending: true,
    });
});
```

Comment: I'll check this..Thanks..:)